# Xcode8.2.1 Cocoapods Generating Pods project [1] 85146 abort

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8.2

Xcode:8.2.1，questions as follows:

`➜  PodTest git:(master) ✗ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (4.2.0)
Generating Pods project
[1]    85146 abort      pod install
➜  PodTest git:(master) ✗ pod --version
1.1.1`

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed on this thread https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6102

The solution, not the best but the easier if you don't wanna know about the problem, was to use cocoapods 1.2.0-beta.1: `gem install cocoapods --pre`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by updating the xcodeproj gem:

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj
```